# I inject package into angular module, why is my package null?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using mongoose to store objects into my db. I have successfully saved an object into the db and now whenever I try and search for it, I get an undefined on "Compositions.query(function...".I have this module, called compositions, and this is the controller for it:

```
angular.module('mean.compositions').controller('CompositionsController', ['$scope','fileUpload' ,'$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Compositions',
  function($scope, fileUpload, $stateParams, $location, Global, Compositions) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.package = {
      name: 'compositions'
    };
$scope.find = function() {
      console.log('get here');
      Compositions.query(function(composition) {
        console.log(composition);
        $scope.composition = composition;
      });
      console.log('pass');
    };
}
```

Now, whenever I try and query Compositions, I get this error:

```
undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.find (http://localhost:3000/modules/aggregated.js:6:644)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10735:21
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12595:28)
    at pre (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19781:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6628:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6039:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5934:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2805:9
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6648:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6039:13) <section data-ng-controller="CompositionsController" data-ng-init="find()" class="ng-scope">
```

I've included the service code.

UPDATE:

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('mean.compositions').factory('Compositions', [
    function() {
        return {
            name: 'compositions'
        };
    }
]);
```

Thanks for any kind of input why I am getting this odd error.

Comment: Can you post the `Compositions` service?

Comment: @AnthonyChu I've updated my post with the service code.

Comment: Sorry I meant the `Compositions` service that is being injected into the controller. What is that and how was it defined?

Comment: @AnthonyChu I am new to angular, but I think the new update should be what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. `Compositions` is just an object with a `name` property. So that explains why you get that error when you try to invoke its non existent `query()` method. Did you mean to return a resource from the factory instead?

Comment: BTW: Don't use concatenated/minified JS files while developing/debugging. It makes the task much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Compositions.query(function(composition) I don't understand this line.I guess, this is something different than written factory function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Composition` is a service created by you with the following code:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.compositions').factory('Compositions', [
    function() {
        return {
            name: 'compositions'
        };
    }
]);
```

The only thing it has is a property called `name` with a value `compositions`. What you are trying to do is to inject `Composition` service into `CompositionsController` and call `query` method on it. Keeping this in mind it's not a puzzler why the whole thing fails with `undefined is not a function` error.

What you *probably* need to do is add a `query` method to the object which is returned by `Compositions` factory function and return something meaningful from there.

```js
return {
    name: 'compositions',
    query: function() { 
        console.log("This is where I have to access my DB'); 
        return ['object1', 'object2', 'object3'] }
    };
```

Comment: This worked, except I used the $resource dependency I defined. Thanks!